No WiFi detected after BIOS update
I have a PC with a Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04 dual boot. I have recently updated the BIOS. After that the WiFi on Ubuntu does not work. It is not finding any possible network to connect to. It works normally on Windows, and the Ethernet connection works fine.
Here are some checks:

lshw -c network

  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 01
       serial: 04:ec:d8:61:bc:32
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.8.0-48-generic firmware=86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.uc latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:620-61f irq:16 memory:6205234000-6205237fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 15
       serial: d8:43:ae:06:bd:ba
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.8.0-48-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 dkms statuslink=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:79204000-79204fff memory:79200000-79203fff 


nmcli d

DEVICE   TYPE      STATE                   CONNECTION 
docker0  bridge    connected (externally)  docker0    
enp3s0   ethernet  unavailable             --         
wlo1     wifi      unavailable             --         
lo       loopback  unmanaged               --  

The ethernet shows available when connected. I am not sure what is the docker about. I used it a while ago.

rfkill list:

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no


lspci -knn | grep Net -A3:

0000:00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi [8086:51f0] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz [8086:0074]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi


cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf

# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211



dkms status:

backport-iwlwifi/11510, 6.8.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)


Remove this backport-iwlwifi package and make a reboot.

@nobody I've done it; nothing seems to change.

I have solved the problem described as the same as yours. I used the instructions at:
https://wireless.docs.kernel.org/en/latest/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi/core_release.html#how-to-install-the-driver

How to install the driver
In order to install the driver, you’ll need to download the sources:
git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git

Then, you can make the sources with vendor commands disabled:
make defconfig-iwlwifi-public
sed -i 's/CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS=y/# CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS is not set/' .config
make -j4

Now it is time to install the modules you built
sudo make install

Now you can reboot.

Important: everything worked only after disabling Secure boot.

It works, thank you very much. I have just one question: should I leave Secure Boot disabled? Is it safe?

Disabling Secure Boot is a temporary measure. It looks like an error has been made somewhere and the Wi-Fi driver is not signed correctly for Linux. After all, everything works well under Windows and with Secure Boot enabled and the same Wi-Fi chip. Over time, everything will be adjusted and the next update will bring a properly working driver.  Then Secure Boot can be enabled again.
